# Find all pairs of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(2x+7y)|(7x+2y)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(2x+7y)|(7x+2y)$.

I tried simple properties but couldn't arrive at any other conclusion other than the obvious $x=y$.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Let $k(2x+7y)=7x+2y$

$\implies \dfrac x{7k-2}=\dfrac y{7-2k}$

If $x,y >0$ we need $(7k-2)(7-2k)>0$

Comment: Could you explain why we need $(7k-2)(7-2k)>0$?

Comment: @mfl, As $x,y$ are positive integers

Comment: I don't see why $x,y$ must be positive integers. Indeed, $x=-2,y=7$ is a possible pair.

Comment: @mfl, please find the updated answer

Comment: In other words, $k\in \{1,2,3\}.$ I see now your idea. It also works if $x,y<0.$

Comment: It follows from the answer that $(x,y)=(7k-2,7-2k)$ is a solution for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: @mfl, More generally $$(7k-2)m, (7-2k)m$$ for integer $m$

Answer (score 1):

**@lab bhattarjee**'s answer is complete assuming $x,y>0$ or $x,y<0.$ In such a case $(7k-2)(7-2k)>0$ or, equivalently, $k=1,2$ or $3.$ This, gives us, $x=y,$ $x=4y$ and $x=19y,$ respectively.

Also, it follows from his answer that $$(x,y)=((7k-2)m,(7-2k)m)$$ is a solution for every $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Next I am going to show that these are the only solutions.

It follows from $k(2x+7y)=7x+2y$ that $$2y\equiv 2kx \mod 7.$$ Thus, $$y\equiv kx \mod 7.$$ That is, $$y=kx+7c.$$ So, we have $$x=\dfrac{c(2-7k)}{k^2-1},$$ assuming $k\ne \pm 1.$ Since $\dfrac{2-7k}{k^2-1}$ is never an integer, unless $k=0,$ it must be $c=m(k^2-1).$ So, $$x=(2-7k)m$$ and $$y=(2k-7)m.$$

It is clear that $x=y$ and $x=-y$ are solutions (in these cases one gets $c=0$). So, it only remain to dicuss the case $k=0.$ In this case $y=7c$ and $x=-2c.$ This case is included in the general solution we have given.

Comment: How are you getting that $x=c(2-7k)/(k^2-1)$?